# DataGridTextColumn DateTime Binding date format

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyDate" Binding="{Binding Path=MyDate, 
StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyym\}}" />
```

The data is displayed in the correct format but when i edit the cell it swaps the month and day.What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you may have to work on some styling):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyDate">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyym\}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyym\}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I have tested it in my demo app and it works just fine. There must be some other styling applied to your controls which overrides my code, causing problems.